# Getting PHP to receive AJAX data

Tags: php, json, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send data (such as the value of a HTML input element) from one script to another (or to the same script if possible) without any HTML form element, instead using a JavaScript event and a XMLHttpRequest (no jQuery please).

I've tried different headers and content types.

I've tried GET, POST, PATCH, and PUT methods.

I've tried receiving with $_SESSION, $_POST, $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], etc. and even file_get_contents('php://input').

I've tried var_dump, print_r, json_decode, etc.

I've poured through solutions, details, and gotchas from similar questions, other websites and blogs, and various books. While I've learned a ton, this still isn't working...

I could be mistaken, but according to the Chrome and Firefox dev tools at least, it appears the data is being sent just fine from the client-side, so I believe the issue is with PHP (or perhaps my hosting provider's server config?).

If I could just get the PHP script to receive the data, I'll be good to go. From there, I know how to process it, insert it into a MySQL database, etc.

**What I'm looking for:** a simple, working example of JSON data sent to a PHP script (initiated by, say, a JS click event).

Thank you

Comment: sounds like you want a solution without a proper question

Comment: I would suggest downloading firefox developer edition, open the console window,click the network tab and do your post. If you say that the data is being sent correctly, it should display a status and also a response.. check the response on the php script.. it might be something small

Comment: Forbs, if you could provide evidence that my question is improper as defined by this website's guidelines, I will gladly edit my question to make it proper. From my current understanding, it is a proper question.

Comment: Christopher Smit, I have already checked all that numerous times. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Recheck the name for the input value you sent from your script, then recheck the method either post or delete etc. Make sure the receiving party accept using the same name, and the same method. Have you tried receiving using **$_REQUEST['input_name']**?
Are you sure you send to the right url/action?

Comment: Muhammad Habib, I have tried all of that. Thank you for your suggestion though.